# 'implicit' in Scala not working as thought

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

In order to understand how 'implicit' works in Scala, I have written following code but it doesn't give me the expected result.

I thought I understood the use of 'implicit' (which clearly is not true). I have three classes, Plant, Dog and myPet. Dog has a function 'sound' which returns "woof". Plant has a function "tallOrShort" which returns "tall". These functions describe features of Dog and Plant.

I want to write a generic code in myPet to which I can pass an instance of Dog or Plant. I call this function 'describe'.  The describe function should print "woof" for Dog instances and "tall" for Plant instances.

Dog and Plant are independent classes (no subtype). I thought I can use 'implicit' to "add" this functionality in Dog and Plant class. My understanding is that by using implicit, Dog or Plant could be implicitly converted into 'something' which can then call 'sound' or 'tallOrShort' for Dog and Plant respectively. I have written following code but it doesn't work.

I started with Dog class to begin with

```
//create Dog
scala> class Dog {
| def sound = "woof"
| }

defined class Dog

//create trait (the contract interface which Dog can be member of
scala> trait myPetTrait[A] {
| def describePet(a:A):String
| }

defined trait myPetTrait

//implicit conversion should happen using this code?
scala> implicit object dogIsPet extends myPetTrait[Dog] {
| def describePet(d:Dog) = d.sound
| }

defined object dogIsPet
```

Now first, I thought of defining only a generic function 'describe' as follows but I am not able to pass Dog or Plant instance to it.

```
//'describe' function. It should work for both Dog and Plant
scala> def describe[A](implicit pt:myPetTrait[A]) = {println(pt.describePet(_:A))}
describe: [A](implicit pt: myPetTrait[A])Unit

scala> describe(new Dog)
<console>:21: error: type mismatch;
found   : Dog
required: myPetTrait[?] 
describe(new Dog)
```

**Question 1 - What is wrong with above? Shouldn't Dog get converted to myPetTrait[Dog]?**

Then I thought to create a class (myPet) and define 'describe' in that class. That doesn't work either

```
//metPet It should work for both Dog and Plant       
scala> class myPet[A](a:A) {
| def describe[A](implicit pt:myPetTrait[A]) = {println(pt.describePet(_:A))}
| }
defined class myPet

scala> new myPet(new Dog).describe
<function1>
```

**Question 2 - Why does this compile at least if I put describe in myPet? Why am I getting a function literal (function1), not the print I expect**

To keep experimenting, I started REPL again and declared Plant as well before creating describe and myPet

```
//new REPL session. created Dog  
scala> class Dog {
| def sound = "woof"
| }
defined class Dog

//created plant
scala> class Plant {
| def tallOrShort = "tall"
| }

defined class Plant
//created trait
scala> trait myPetTrait[A] {
| def describePet(a:A):String
| }

defined trait myPetTrait

//code which should I think help in implicit conversion
scala> implicit object plantIsPet extends myPetTrait[Plant] {
| def describePet(p:Plant)  = p.tallOrShort
| }
defined object plantIsPet

//describe still doesn't work
//describe shuold work for both Plant and Animal
scala> def describe[A](implicit pt:myPetTrait[A]) = {println(pt.describePet(_:A))}
describe: [A](implicit pt: myPetTrait[A])Unit

//not sure why this error comes
scala> describe(new Dog)
<console>:21: error: type mismatch;
found   : Dog
required: myPetTrait[?] 
describe(new Dog)

//get ambiguity error in this line
scala> new myPet(new Dog).describe     //myPet gives ambiguity error
```

I get ambiguous implicit values error stating that both object dogIsPet of type dogIsPet.type and object plantIsPet of type plantIsPet.type match expected type myPetTrait[A]

**Question 3 - why does Scala complain of ambiguity? It is probably because dogIsPet.type and plantisPet.type are of same 'type'. How do I make this code work?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed this (`describe` must take `a` of type `A` and an `implicit` contract)

define `describe` like this in `myPet`

```
class myPet[A](a:A) {
 def describe(implicit pt:myPetTrait[A]) = {
   println(pt.describePet(a))
 }
}
```

`describe` outside the `myPet` can be declared like this

```
def describe[A](a: A)(implicit pt:myPetTrait[A]) = {println(pt.describePet(a))}
```

Scala has a special syntax for this

```
def describe[A: myPetTrait](a: A) = println(implicitly[myPetTrait[A]].describePet(a))
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> def describe[A](a: A)(implicit pt:myPetTrait[A]) = {println(pt.describePet(a))}
describe: [A](a: A)(implicit pt: myPetTrait[A])Unit

scala> describe[Plant](new Plant)
tall
```

or use scala syntactic sugar

```
scala> def describe[A: myPetTrait](a: A) = println(implicitly[myPetTrait[A]].describePet(a))
describe: [A](a: A)(implicit evidence$1: myPetTrait[A])Unit

scala> describe[Plant](new Plant)
tall

scala> trait myPetTrait[A] { def describePet(a:A):String } 
defined trait myPetTrait

scala> class Dog { def sound = "woof" } 
defined class Dog

scala> implicit object dogIsPet extends myPetTrait[Dog] { def describePet(d:Dog) = d.sound }  
defined object dogIsPet

scala> def describe[A: myPetTrait](a: A) = println(implicitly[myPetTrait[A]].describePet(a)) 
defined function describe

scala> implicit object dogIsPet extends myPetTrait[Dog] { def describePet(d:Dog) = d.sound }  
defined object dogIsPet

scala> describe[Dog](new Dog) 
woof

scala> class myPet[A](a:A) {
      def describe(implicit pt:myPetTrait[A]) = {
        println(pt.describePet(a))
      }
    } 
defined class myPet

scala> new myPet[Dog](new Dog).describe 
woof
```

Complete code at one place

Main.scala

```
object Implicits {
  trait myPetTrait[A] {
    def describePet(a:A):String
  }

  class Dog {
    def sound = "woof"
  }

  class Plant {
    def tallOrShort = "tall"
  }

  //evidence for Plant
  implicit object plantIsPet extends myPetTrait[Plant] {
    def describePet(p:Plant)  = p.tallOrShort
  }

  //evidence for Dog
  implicit object dogIsPet extends myPetTrait[Dog] {
    def describePet(d:Dog) = d.sound
  }

  def describe[A](a: A)(implicit pt:myPetTrait[A]) = {
    println(pt.describePet(a))
  }

  //syntactic sugar
  def describe2[A : myPetTrait](a: A) =
    println(implicitly[myPetTrait[A]].describePet(a))

  class myPet[A](a:A) {
    def describe(implicit pt:myPetTrait[A]) = {
      println(pt.describePet(a))
    }
  }

}


object Main {

  import Implicits._

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    describe(new Dog)
    describe(new Plant)
    describe2(new Dog)
    describe2(new Plant)

    new myPet[Dog](new Dog).describe
    new myPet[Plant](new Plant).describe
  }
}
```

output:

```
woof
tall
woof
tall
woof
tall
```

Comment: @ManuChadha .. i have pasted the exact code ... in the answer

Comment: @ManuChadha tell me where is the problem

Comment: @ManuChadha check the Scala REPL output in the answer once again

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciate your help. One thing stlll doesn't work

I want to use the code in following way

scala> new myPet(new Dog).describe //should print "woof" without passing a Dog variable to describe. Instead, describe should use the Dog variable passed to myPet

//this works following your suggestion but it is not what I want. 
scala> class myPet[A] (a:A){
     | def describe[A](a:A)(implicit pt:myPetTrait[A]) = {println(pt.describePet(a))}
     | }

scala> val d = new Dog

scala> val p = new myPet(d)

scala> p.describe(d) //but I want 'new myPet(new Dog).describe'
woof

Comment: @ManuChadha ... edited the answer ... pasted the complete code to run easily just check

Comment: @ManuChadha edited the answer ... with code for `myPet` class as well just check

Comment: @ManuChadha delcare you `myPet` class like this `class myPet[A](a:A) {
 def describe(implicit pt:myPetTrait[A]) = {
   println(pt.describePet(a))
 }
}`

Comment: @ManuChadha hope this helps

Comment: Thank you SIr! It worked. The mistake I was making was that I added type variable in describe when I used it in myPet ( scala> class myPet[A] (a:A){
     | def describe[A](implicit pt:myPetTrait[A]) = {println(pt.describePet(a))}
     | } ). I noticed that you didnt use [A] when you you created 'describe' in myPet. I'll read more to understand the difference between the two.

Comment: @ManuChadha run `Main.scala` by copying to ur local file .. this should solve all ur problems

Comment: @ManuChadha yes